# How to remove white lines of card-img in an img-overlay card?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, overlay

I'm making a web page with some cards in a row with multiple columns using Bootstrap 4.5, but there are white lines in the borders (?) of the `card-img` I can't remove:

[image: Card with sketchy lines]

In the CSS you can observe I'm using padding at `card-img`, trying to determine whether those are border lines or something else, but I don't understand their "parent".

```
<div class="row row-flex d-flex row-black align-items-stretch">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4 card-col">
        <div class="card border-dark">
            <img class="card-img grad-bg1" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="card-img-overlay">
                <h1 class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-flask text-light" aria-hidden="true"></i></h1>
                <h3 class="card-title">Flask!</h3>
                <h5 class="card-text text-center">It's a lab!</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is

```
.row-black {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 286px;
    padding-top: 1.61%;
    padding-bottom: 1.61%;
    padding-left: 6.85% !important;
    padding-right: 6.85% !important;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.card-col {
    margin-top: 1.61%;
    margin-bottom: 1.61%;
}

.card {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border-radius: 30px;
    min-height: 350px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 350px;
    border: none !important;
    background: transparent;
}

.card-img {
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    border: none !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

.card-img-overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    border: none !important;
}

.card-title {
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
}

.grad-bg1 {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(60, 176, 219, 1) 0%, rgba(6, 26, 85, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(60, 176, 219, 1) 0%, rgba(6, 26, 85, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(60, 176, 219, 1) 0%, rgba(6, 26, 85, 1) 100%);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that "border" comes from the missing src attribute on your image tag.

You can achieve what you need without it or you can simply add a src to the image tag.

HTML

```
 <div class="row row-flex d-flex row-black align-items-stretch">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4 card-col">
    <div class="card border-dark">
      <div class="card-img-overlay grad-bg1">
        <h1 class="text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-flask text-light" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </h1>
        <h3 class="card-title">Flask!</h3>
        <h5 class="card-text text-center">It's a lab!</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row-black {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 286px;
    padding-top: 1.61%;
    padding-bottom: 1.61%;
    padding-left: 6.85% !important;
    padding-right: 6.85% !important;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .card-col {
    margin-top: 1.61%;
    margin-bottom: 1.61%;
  }

  .card {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border-radius: 30px;
    min-height: 350px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 350px;
    border: none !important;
    background: transparent;
  }

  .card-img-overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    border: none !important;
  }

  .card-title {
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
  }

  .grad-bg1 {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
      135deg,
      rgba(60, 176, 219, 1) 0%,
      rgba(6, 26, 85, 1) 100%
    );
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
      135deg,
      rgba(60, 176, 219, 1) 0%,
      rgba(6, 26, 85, 1) 100%
    );
    background: linear-gradient(
      135deg,
      rgba(60, 176, 219, 1) 0%,
      rgba(6, 26, 85, 1) 100%
    );
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none !important;

    border-radius: 30px;
  }
```

Demo

https://codepen.io/vagelisp/pen/yLaeMVg

Comment: Spot on! I was messing with filters on an image, changed my approach using gradient backgrounds, but forgot changing `img` to `div`. Thanks!